# Multiplying two arrays of np.random.normal distributions with for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, normal-distribution

This is an extension from my previous question:
I'm trying to create a normal distribution for each value in a list and use a for loop as its 6,000 numbers. My code looks like:

```
for x in data:
   r[x]=np.random.normal(data['value'],data['Standard Deviation'],100000)
```

and I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

I changed my code to the StackOverflow suggestion:

```
r = np.random.normal(data['value'], data['Standard Deviation'], (100000, len(data))).T
```

Which ran successfully. I am now trying to do some arithmetic with this distribution array and other columns from the dataframe:

```
for y in data:
    y=(100000,len(data['value2']))
```

`z= y*((1+r)**10)`

and am getting the following error:
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (12,100000)

The code runs fine if I grab the first value for each array:

```
z=y[0]*((1+r[0])**10)
```

but doesn't work if I try to run it through the entire array. My goal is to take data['value2'] and grow it by the array of normal distributions for growth rate r.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Add the code that creates `y` to the question.

Comment: Please make reproducible example and show exactly what you expect to achieve